# "lastcell" issue with formula in complete column in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I'm currently using a formula throughout a column in an Excel 2010 worksheet. It works fine, but I'm not really using the entire worksheet, I only don't want to have to worry about adding the formula every time I add a row with data. Because the excel thinks that the last significant row is the last row with a formula in it, I get a worksheet >1000000 rows long, which makes it a pain to scroll through the data already added.

Is there any work around to this problem? I have tried some kind of dynamic macro changing the scroll area of my worksheet, but I haven't gotten it to work.

Comment: Share your macro with us so we can see if we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I have two solutions for you:

- Convert your data to a  table (insert - table) and you won't need to worry about formula auto fill when you add new data, so your users range will be really the range you use.
- If the previous solution doesn't work: select a cell in a data column (not one with pre-filled formulas that extend forever) and press CTRL+ DOWN ARROW.  That will jump to the last cell used in that column (only if there are no blank cells in the column).

Comment: On your second suggestion, doesn't that also work with formulas?

Comment: Yes it works with formulas too, but that's not a solution for him as formulas are filled down until end of the sheet and he wants to go until end of his table only.